# jQuery div slide to left on hover a div/nextarrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to implement something like this http://www.jamieoliver.com (slider -> arrow on hover)

I have done this much http://jsfiddle.net/PXLJG/5/ In the jsfiddle script? The arrow must be stand. The div.class=content 'Text next article' must be slide to left next to the arrow.

```
$('.holdingbox').hover(function () {
    $('.rightbox').stop().animate({
        width : '120px'
    }, 400)
}, function () {
    $('.rightbox').stop().animate({
        width : '-0'
    }, 400)
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="holdingbox">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="margined">
            <div class="rightbox">
                <div class="content"><p>Következő cikk</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="leftbox"> > </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    div {
    display : inline-block;
}

.holdingbox {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.leftbox {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #ac193d;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1px;
}

.holdingbox a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
}

.leftbox img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.rightbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.rightbox a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
}

.content {
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ac193d;
    height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}

.content p {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Could you try to clarify?

Comment: I'd like to make a next arrow/button like on jamieoliver.com slider with my jsfiddle script, as you can see on jamieoliver.com the next button on hover the arrow a div slides to left as "More videos"
So how can I fix my jsfiddle script like that?:/ (while hover on arrow a div slidin to left behind the arrow and the arrow must stand on hover.) Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2):

just add `position: absolute; right: 0;` in `.rightbox` class.

```
.rightbox {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0;
}
```

**Working here - http://jsfiddle.net/PXLJG/7/**

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `inline-block` style on all `div`s. Please revert to normal display of `block`.

```
div{
    display: block;
}
```

or just remove it as the default display is `block`

http://jsfiddle.net/PXLJG/8/

That should solve your core issue.

Now if you want to show the arrow to the left of the text div, remove `absolute` position on the arrow.

Now you will be having a whitespace between the `inline-block` elements, that is the arrow and the text. To remove it easily remove the whitespace between those two `div` in `HTML`

http://jsfiddle.net/PXLJG/18/

For something exactly like as in the website, you can try positioning both arrow and text using absolute positioning and anchoring them with their `right` property.

This way, as the width increases it will expand from right to left.

http://jsfiddle.net/PXLJG/20/

Comment: this does not work as OP wants. The example site shows the arrow element is not supposed to move, and the text is supposed to expand out towards the left.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes, there was some difficult understanding what OP wanted. I have expanded the answer. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix up the code you've already got but it needed some major rehauling so I've just re-done it all.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t2z9Q/

`CSS`

```
.container {
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}

.container .content {
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
    float:left;
    z-index: 99;
    background: #ac193d;
}

.container .arrow {
    float: right;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #ac193d;
}
```

`JS`

```
$('.arrow').hover(function() {
    $('.container .content').stop().animate({left: '0'}, 400)
}, function() {
   $('.container .content').stop().animate({left: '120px'}, 400)
});
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Next Article</div>
    <div class="arrow">></div>    
</div>
```

This way you lose a lot of the jargon html & css that isn't really required but still get the same effect.